# Universal CSS Engine recommended for Swing applications or alternative library

Tags: java, swing, java-7, css

It seems the Universal CSS Engine is quite old and not actively developed (the last code change was over a year ago and just 25 code changes / commits in total).

Has someone experiences with it and could recommend it or a good, active alternative library for Java applications based on Swing?

https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-css-engine/

There was also an approach some years ago: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/10/14/swingcss.html

Tk-UI is also old but mentioned: http://myblog.chaiware.org/2009/12/coding-java-gui-using-swing-designing.html

Found this but there are no real documentations or examples: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cssparser/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has someone experiences with it and could recommend it or a good,
>   active alternative?

- [use JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm), supporting Html5, JavaScript, CSS Styles
- you can embededd JavaFX2.x to Swing container,
- notice there are some restictions in compare Swing/Swing v.s. Swing/JavaFX2.x
- everything will be changed in Java8 with JavaFX8 (Swing in JavaFX, Swing and JavaFX side_on_side, and vice_versa)

Comment: JavaFX is not an option currently, also embedding JavaFX. I know that there are restrictions but I need a solution for Swing as the whole application is created using Swing. Java8 is many miles away. And Java7 will be still actively developed. I also do not plan to switch to Java8 directly because I use many thirdparty libraries with several dependecies. ;-)

Comment: forgot about Java7, there are a fews bugs in JTextComponents, you can to compile in Java6, or or buy a plane, really fast bike and waiting for 1st Java8, all 3rd. party (free) Frameworks died with owner changes from Sun to Oracle, then there were everything stopped, some have survived to this day only from enthusiasm, or inertia, Html support in Java6/7 is reduced upto 3.2version, with reduced support for CSS, hard to create any miracles

Comment: I have another opinion. Did I mention JTextComponents? The thirdparty libraries I use (from Apache) did not die ;-) I know the restrictions, I just need it to style specific elements (color of text and background), so no miracles at all. Just need a way to define the values in a css file and a library which applies it to the components (like Java Universal CSS engine does actually)